# Pulling data from website onto Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

From this link [Baseball-Reference](https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/split.fcgi?id=bumgama01&year=Career&t=p) scrolling down to table 16 (Batting Order Positions)
[image]

From the table i tried using =importhtml with no luck. Can IMPORTXML be used to pull the data and maybe just pull the highlighted section tOPS+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
    =let(z,importxml("https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/split.fcgi?id=bumgama01&year=Career&t=p","//*[@id=""all_lineu""]/comment()"),
sort(tocol(index(iferror(--regexextract(trim(split(substitute(z,char(10)," ")," Bat",0)),"[^\s]*$"),"tOPS+"))),1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: You are awesome!! Also would there be any documentation i can read to explain how you got to this formula?